# math-python converting statistics equation to code

Tags: python, statistics

Trying to solve a problem about Dungeons and Dragons dice rolls. Anyway, I came up with this equation from the following site https://www.desmos.com/calculator/6kylcryv0m:
[image]

where

```
d = 12
m = 10.5
q = 5
```

Really new with python and statistics and i just need help on how to convert this step by step to python code so i could study it in chunks.

Comment: What's the value of s?

Comment: from our lessons i believe it is supposed to be sigma or Var(X)

Comment: i just derived it from this website: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/6kylcryv0m 

it's at the bottom

Comment: It sounds like you have a working solution already, but something that might help you understand where this formula is coming from -- take a look at "central limit theorem" and "normal approximation to binomial distribution". It appears the formula is a tail probability for a normal distribution -- it could be coming from either of those two things I mentioned. Good luck and have fun,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here we go, this will work. You will need to install scipy and numpy if you haven't already.

```
from numpy import sqrt, sin, cos, pi, exp
from scipy.integrate import quad

def integrand(x,m,q,s):
    return ((1)/(s*sqrt(2*pi))) * exp(-(x-m-q)**2/(2*s**2))

d = 12
m = 10.5
q = 5
s = 5.78
I = quad(integrand, d, 1000, args=(m,q,s))
print(I[0])
```

Reference page:
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/integrate.html

You can ask me any questions about anything that doesn't make sense.

Comment: Thank you so much it worked!!! last few questions. If you were to manually do scipy.integrate.quad manually in python, how would it be? and how did you get the value of sigma?? :)

Comment: For very complex integrations, attempting to get the exact solutions would be astronomically difficult. However, this integral isn't as hard as it looks... Have you done integration in class before? If not, I'll break it down for you.

Comment: honestly i just need to convert `quad` into it's close estimate in manual python so i could understand how it works

Comment: Oops, I missed that 2 in the numerator of the exponential. That's a lot harder. The integral of e^ax is 1/a * e^ax + c, search for Integration of Exponential Functions on google. With the squared, you're going to need to type in the function that when differentiated gives you the original equation. Best of luck!

Comment: This is a big help already! No worries. I kinda get the idea now. :) Thank you so much! Wishing you all the best as well!